# ngRoute can't get data from one view to another

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

### Angular.JS issue with ng-repeat value from inputs

I'm having an issue with ng-repeat, where I can't see to get the values from the input to show on the UI when submitted.

I'm very new to angular JS, hence why I'm trying to build a simple to do app to learn the basics.

On the newItem.html page, there is a form with a function Add(). There are two inputs for the project and the title. There is a button to add the new to do item.

Once the button is clicked and it runs the Add() function, it should add a new object to the toDoList array with the Project and the Task.

On the homePage.html I want to display a project title and the task details. Later down the line I want to generate the entire row on each click but for now I'm just trying to get the text to change.

I'm obviously missing something obvious here, I've read through the documentation for ng-repeat and ng-model, but just can't seem to grasp it.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="ToDoListApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>To Do App</title>
    <script src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.module.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/assets/css/home.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Acme&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4c765e5630.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body ng-view ng-controller="toDoCtrl">


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**homePage.html**

```
<div class="row header">
    <div class="col-12">
        <h1>DOINGO</h1>
        <p>0 Open Tasks</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row toDoList">

    <div class="row newItem">
        <div class="col-2">
            <button class="itemComplete btn"><i class="far fa-check-circle fa-2x"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <h4 ng-repeat="Project in ToDoList">{{ToDoList.Project}}</h4>
            <p ng-repeat="Task in ToDoList">{{ToDoList.Task}}.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <button class="btn deleteItem"><i class="far fa-times-circle fa-2x"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row addItemRow">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <a href="#/newItem"><button type="button" class="btn btn addItem">
                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-3x"></i>
            </button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**newItem.html**

```
    <div class="row header">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1>DOINGO</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row addNewItem">
        <form ng-submit='Add()' class="form">
            <div class="row projectInput text-center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="ToDoList.Project" placeholder="Enter a project title" ng-required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row taskInput text-center">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="ToDoList.Task" placeholder="Enter your task details" ng-required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttonRow row">
                <div class="col-12 text-center">
                    <a href="#/"><button type="submit" class="btn-lg btn-success addItemButton">Add</button></a>
        </form>
        <a href="#/"><button class="btn-lg btn-danger cancelButton">Cancel</button></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

### app.module.js

```
var app = angular.module('ToDoListApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

    $routeProvider   
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "app/home/homePage.html",
        controller: "toDoCtrl"
    })
    .when("/newItem", {
        templateUrl: "app/newItem/newitem.html",
        controller: "toDoCtrl"
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    })
});

//main controller for app functionality

app.controller('toDoCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.ToDoList = []

    //add the new to do item to the array
    $scope.Add = function () {
        $scope.ToDoList.push({
            Project: $scope.Project,
            Task: $scope.Task
        });
        $scope.Project = '';
        $scope.Task = '';
    };
});
```

Comment: In the ng-repeat you need to create a reference todo in ToDoList then your model would be todo.Project / todo.Task. You can name your reference anything you want. I feel like you should move your repeat into the div class="col-8" and then iterate over each project and task on the same line.

Comment: It is not wise to instantiate the same controller twice using both the ngRouter and the ng-controller directive, Also not wise to have `<script>` tags inside an `ng-view` element.

Comment: @georgeawg I have removed the reference to the controller in the ngRouter. I have also moved the scripts out of the view element, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Mickers, are you able to provide and example of what you are suggesting? I have added a reference as you have suggested but still nothing happens on the UI after I have added input values to the array.

Comment: Keep in mind that when the router changes views, it destroys the controller for the old view and creates an new instance of a controller for the new view. Data on the scope of the old controller is destroyed.

Comment: Something like this:
<div class="col-8" ng-repeat="obj in ToDoList">
<h4>{{obj.Project}}</h4>
<p>{{obj.Task}}.</p>
</div>

Comment: @Mickers thanks for the example. But why do we bother with a reference to obj? I haven't mentioned obj anywhere else so why do we use a reference name for the ng-repeat?

Comment: @georgeawg if the data is destroyed how can you transfer data from one view to another? Do I need to set up a service or function to store the data and then get the data on the view I want to use it?

Comment: The purpose was to show you that the name isn't important. It appeared like you were getting confused in the code you provided for how that worked.

Comment: If you were to keep the original code you'd need at least to change this: <h4 ng-repeat="Project in ToDoList">{{Project.Project}}</h4> "Project" is your ToDoList object and "Project.Project" is the value you're trying to access. Naming it this way doesn't make sense so I renamed it to obj.

Comment: Use services to contain data that presists between views.